# Display name instead of id in url laravel

Tags: laravel

I would just like to ask how do I display the name of the business instead of it's id.
It's currently displayed like this, localhost:8000/1/Belen'sChoice and desired output is
localhost:8000/Belen'sChoice. I can get the name however it says 'trying to find id'.

Controller

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $businesses = Business::find($id);
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $users = User::where('id', $userId)->get();
        $posts = Post::where('business_id', $businesses->id)->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
        $supporters = Supporter::where('user_id', $userId)->get();
        $photos = Image::where('business_id', $businesses->id)->get();
        $albums = Album::where('business_id', $businesses->id)->get();

        $count = 0;

        if ($businesses->user_id != Auth::user()->id) {
            $businesses->views = $businesses->views + 1;
            $businesses->save();
        } else {
            $businesses->views = $businesses->views;
        }

        return view('businesses.index', [
            'categories' => $categories,
            'businesses' => $businesses,
            'users' => $users,
            'posts' => $posts,
            'supporters' => $supporters,
            'count' => $count,
            'images' => $photos,
            'albums' => $albums,
            ]);
    } else {
        return view('businesses.index', [
        'categories' => $categories,
        'businesses' => $businesses,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Blade

```
<a class="text-center" href='{{ url("/businessprofile/".$business->id."/".str_replace(" ", "" ,$business->name)) }}'><img class="bprof-img" src='{{ asset("storage/$business->logo") }}'>{{ $business->name }}</a>
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/businessprofile/{id?}/{name}', 'BusinessController@show');
```

TIA

Comment: Could you try ``Route::get('/businessprofile/{name}-{id}', 'BusinessController@show');``

Comment: wont it just show /businessprofile/Belen'sChoice-1  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**take one Column in your business migration**

```
$table->string('slug')->unique();
```

and save it like this way in your controller

```
//use this at the bottom of your controller

    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
            $business = new Business;
            $business->slug = Str::slug($request->name) // whatever you request dring //creating a business row
        //and after that save it
        $business->save();
```

then in your controller find the row using slug

```
public function show($slug)
{
$business = Business::where('slug',$slug)->first();
```

//and rest of your operation
}

href='{{ url("/".str_replace(" ", "" ,$business->slug))}}'
then in your web

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'BusinessController@show');
```

Comment: hi! this is the output http://localhost:8000/Belen'sChoice2.

Comment: I wish for it to display localhost:8000/Belen'sChoice only and not show the id.

Comment: yes I've also tried that but the problem with that is it does not find the id of the business.

Comment: oh... I got your problem.wait i will update my answer

Comment: sure. it would be a great help

Comment: check it now am sure it will helps you

Comment: BRO IT WORKED! I'VE BEEN FINDING THE ANSWER FOR DAYS! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I was wondering, the business->name is also unique but why cant I make it work using
show($name)?

Comment: slug is the most used by everywhere as like you can see  this question link which is geneartaed by slug "display-name-instead-of-id-in-url-laravel" and by using Str::slug() you can get this type of output

Comment: I see. and maybe to avoid finding duplicates? thank you so much Tanvir I wish you all the best!